# Is the superuser beta invite-only?

Tags: discussion

I always wished I never missed out on the SO beta, so, I really wanted into the SU-beta party. But there's no application anywhere--it seems to be invite only. This left me...Disappointed.

But am I wrong? Is it too late to join the party?

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing.

Comment: check http://blog.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

Jeff has mentioned it's good to point people to the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/) so if they ever need to update the password you won't be out of date.

Comment: great, thanks for filling me in